# Ошибка при подключении django к mongodb с помощью djongo

Tags: python, django, mongodb

Не так давно начал изучать django. Возникла необходимость использовать mongodb.
Нашел в интернете модуль Djongo. Установил с помощью команды `pip install djongo`. Потом проверил версию, показало 1.3.6.

Я специально создал новый проект на django, где с шаблона сайта взял такой кусочек:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'CLIENT': {
           'host': '127.0.0.1',
        }
    }
}
```

mongo у меня стоит, база данный есть. При попытке запустить сайт вылетает такая ошибка:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'djongo' isn't an available database backend or couldn't be imported. Check the above exception. To use one of the built-in backends, use 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
```

Templates:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

installed_apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'djongo'
]
```

(djongo туда добавил потому, что думал, что решит проблему. но это не помогло)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смешная ситуация произошла...
Как только я задал вопрос, так и сразу нашел решение.

помогло : `pip install pytz`